# SortByValue for a RDD of tuples

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Recently I was asked (in a class assignment) to find the top 10 occurring words inside RDD. I submitted my assignment with a working solution which looks like

```
wordsRdd
  .map(x => (x, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .map(case (x, y) => (y, x))
  .sortByKey(false)
  .map(case (x, y) => (y, x))
  .take(10)
```

So basically, I swap the tuple, sort by key, and then swap again. Then finally take 10. I don't find the repeated swapping very elegant.

So I wonder if there is a more elegant way of doing this.

I searched and found some people using Scala `implicits` to convert the RDD into a Scala Sequence and then doing the `sortByValue`, but I don't want to convert RDD to a Scala `Seq`, because that will kill the distributed nature of the RDD.

So is there a better way?

Comment: "Recently I was asked to find the top 10 occurring words inside rdd" Yeah, right, "An assignment for my course asked..." maybe?

Comment: yes. it was an assignment. I completed it and the results are shown above. I am not asking anyone complete the assignment. I am asking how to improve an answer which is already accepted as working and correct. but I felt there can be a better way.

Comment: Ok. Worth saying that up front or it looks like you're looking for SO to answer your assignment

Comment: not true. I have published a working solution in my question. I wasn't very happy with the repeated swapping.

Comment: I was just saying say it's an assignment first. I agree (now you've added comments) you weren't after an answer from SO

Comment: Your solution wasn't actually correct. The order relation over your RDD elements is not guaranteed after your third map transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
wordsRdd.
    map(x => (x, 1)).
    reduceByKey(_ + _).
    takeOrdered(10)(Ordering.by(-1 * _._2))
```

or a little bit more verbose:

```
object WordCountPairsOrdering extends Ordering[(String, Int)] {
    def compare(a: (String, Int), b: (String, Int)) = b._2.compare(a._2)
}

wordsRdd.
    map(x => (x, 1)).
    reduceByKey(_ + _).
    takeOrdered(10)(WordCountPairsOrdering)
```

Comment: yes. this is much better than my solution. because you are sorting once rather than swaping, sorting and then swapping.  Thanks!